# How to restrict access to Office365 services for hourly employees?

Tags: powershell, office365, user-management

I need to figure out how to restrict access to Office365 services for our hourly employees. We sync using DirSync only - we don't have ADFS. I'm hoping there is some powershell command I can run on a schedule that can disable their account at 5:00pm and enable their account at 8:00am every work day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Set-MsolUser` like this to disable users completely:

```
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName <User Principal Name> -blockcredential $True
```

But you can also control the access more granular. For more Info look here:
[Disable access to service](http://o365info.com/disable-access-to-service/)

Comment: Thanks.
I did research before asking. If I was as smart as you, maybe I'd be the one answering questions instead of asking them. Next time, please don't be a jerk before knowing what a person did before asking the question.

Comment: I am sorry, i do not mean to be a jerk. It seems what i consider basic research skills is not as basic as i thought when i take a look at half the questions with the powershell tag.

Comment: It's ok. The only powershell knowledge I have is duplicating the commands I find on the net when I need something specific - which is rare. If I found I needed a wider knowledge of it, I'd probably take a class. Thanks again for the answer!